# android live wallpaper locking up

Tags: android

I'm very new to android development and to get started I've started modifying the android ask sample 'shape wallpaper'. I've added a touch ripple, change resources etc and removed the more basic example. If I have my se xperia x10 plugged in and run the app it downloads to the phone and once started works great. I then unplug the phone and the wallpaper keeps working for approximately 24 hours. It then slows redrawing dramatically then displays nothing - I can't even load the settings page! 
Anyone have any ideas why? Do I need to do a compilation outside eclipse? I've got the source on Google code which i'll add a link to once I can get on pc (typing this on phone).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Source is here: http://code.google.com/p/shapelivewallpaper/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I know why..yes you need to modify some code, see:

[Richard Green's GLSurfaceView adapted for LiveWallpapers](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers)

That should fix the problem, I use the code myself with no problems.